# HtmlUnit failing on invalid javascript, can it be corrected on client?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I need to load the Discord login page but am failing on javascript exceptions.

Is this an issue that I can resolve on my client or is the javascript simply invalid and HtmlUnit will never process it correctly?

My java code:

```java
webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setHistorySizeLimit(5);
webClient.getOptions().setMaxInMemory(524288000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

webClient.getPage("https://discordapp.com/login");
```

The tail of the exception being thrown (StackOverflow did not allow me to post more of the log)

```
Jul 30, 2019 3:30:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlLink onAllChildrenAddedToPage
WARNING: Link type 'chrome-webstore-item' not supported.
Jul 30, 2019 3:30:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlLink onAllChildrenAddedToPage
WARNING: Link type 'stylesheet' not supported.
Jul 30, 2019 3:30:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlLink onAllChildrenAddedToPage
WARNING: Link type 'icon' not supported.
Jul 30, 2019 3:30:42 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener scriptException
SEVERE: Error during JavaScript execution
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[49] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://discordapp.com/assets/0765c293b8e5eac16193.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function setPrototypeOf in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://discordapp.com/assets/0765c293b8e5eac16193.js#49)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function setPrototypeOf in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://discordapp.com/assets/0765c293b8e5eac16193.js#49)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:885)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:765)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:741)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:997)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:754)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1175)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1115)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:303)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2075)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:922)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:438)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:389)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:997)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:252)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:196)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:159)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:531)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:398)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:466)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
    at discordBot.DiscordWatcher.homePage(DiscordWatcher.java:33)
    at discordBot.MainForDiscordWatcher.main(MainForDiscordWatcher.java:8)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function setPrototypeOf in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://discordapp.com/assets/0765c293b8e5eac16193.js#49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4334)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4312)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4345)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Comment: 'Cannot find function setPrototypeOf in object' points to a problem in HtmlUnit (and in the end in Rhino). Please open an issue on github.

Comment: @RBRi done - https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/64